# Symfony 5 - Inject Security service in Entity doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

I try to get security service in an Entity.
When i want to access it in my entity, the property "$this->security" is null

[image]

See the entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Production;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MarqueRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Marque
{
    /* Others properties useless in the stackoverflow question*/

    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        dd($this->security);
    }

}
```

Autowiring is active in "services.yaml".
I removed the folder "Entity" in the "exclude src"
[image]

Could you help me ? Thxs

Comment: you should NOT inject a service into an entity as it violates DDD and SOLID principles. entities are only to represent some domain object, nothing less, nothing more. you should reconsider your architecture

Comment: I totally agree with previous comment. You should NEVER inject in the constructor some services. The constructor of your entity is here to initialize the required fields of your class, that's all. You should put the security check on the route/action

Comment: unless of course you don't need this for security check but to retrieve the currently logged in user to automatically add it to your entity...

Answer (score 0):

Bad practice.
As said in comment by Lunin Roman and Mcsky, security check could be made in service/controller/etc.

Comment: It's not so much that you shouldn't inject a service into a Doctrine entity.  Or even that is a bad practice.  But rather that you simply can't.  Doctrine does not even use the constructor when hydrating an entity so there is no spot in the code where Doctrine could use the Symfony container even if it wanted to.  There are active record approaches such as Laravel's Eloquent ORM that allow you to do so.  Pros and cons for each approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was read some commentaries about this bad practice, unless that you just need retrive the currently user id logged. Then it is my case.

```
class Aaaa
   
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        
    }
}
```

---

```
services.yaml
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
        - '../src/Tests/
```

so i got this error..

> Cannot create an instance of App\Entity\Aaaaa from serialized data
> because its constructor requires parameter "security" to be present.

Could by config error?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31812043)